# If($variable == "this" || "that"){?

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to write my `if`statement.
Whats the proper way?

This code will turn true either what's sent in. Even if user has group "store", he will get pass.
why?

**PHP**

```
if($_SESSION['user']['usr_group'] == "admin" || "office"){
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if($_SESSION['user']['usr_group'] == "admin" || "office") { foo() }
```

is the same as:

```
if($_SESSION['user']['usr_group'] == "admin") { foo() }
if("office") { foo() }
```

not

```
if($_SESSION['user']['usr_group'] == "admin") { foo() }
if($_SESSION['user']['usr_group'] == "office") { foo() }
```

`if("office")` will always be true.

You need to be explicit with your comparison each time.

```
if($_SESSION['user']['usr_group'] == "admin" || $_SESSION['user']['usr_group'] == "office") { foo() }
```

or [use `in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) instead.

```
if (in_array($_SESSION['user']['usr_group'], array("admin", "office")) { foo() }
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit — True. I was about to edit that bit out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I feel it would be

```
if($_SESSION['user']['usr_group'] == "admin" || $_SESSION['user']['usr_group'] == "office"){
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your statement, you have added logical OR condition.

It means, if any of the conditions is true, then it will return TRUE.

Even if your variable `$_SESSION['user']['usr_group'] == "admin"` can be false,

The second condition `"office"` will always return true and hence, your if condition is always true.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_SESSION['user']['usr_group'] == "admin" || $_SESSION['user']['usr_group'] == "store")
```

or

```
if(in_array($_SESSION['user']['usr_group'], Array("admin", "store"))
```